# Testing TaskResult celery tasks fails

Tags: python, django-celery

I am trying to use `django_celery_results` in my project. I created a task `add` and a function `add_new(x, y)` in `tasks.py`:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult

@shared_task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    return(x, y)

def add_new(x, y):
    task = add.delay(x, y)
    task_result = TaskResult(task_id=task.task_id)
    return task_result.as_dict()
```

I am testing my functions in `test_tasks.py` like this:

```
from tasks import add, add_new
from nose.tools import eq_
from django.test import override_settings


def test_add_task():
    result = add.apply(args=(4, 4,)).get()
    eq_(result, 8)


@override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
def test_add_new_task():
    result = add_new(4, 4)
    eq_(result['result'], 8)
```

The first test passes, but the second one fails with:

```
AssertionError: None != 8
```

Looking at the list of `TaskResult` objects the latest task is not present. Repeating the test, the `task_id` from the test before is there, but again the latest one is missing and the test fails. So I have the impression that the DB is not updated, even after the task has finished successfully. Trying to execute the functions `add` and `add_new` in a shell, it works perfectly fine. Only running the tests with nose do not work. What do I miss?

Comment: I have the same issue, wondering if it's something related to postgres that doesn't flush correctly?